# php do while loop kept table looping infinitely

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

I executed this code in localhost but it kept looping the table infinitely. How do I fix this? Is there something I should add?  The looping never stops until I click the x button to stop loading the page.

```
 //fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
 //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated
 $query=("SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY songid DESC"); 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

 <html>
 <head>    
  <title>View</title>
</head>

 <body>
     <a href="add.php">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>

<table width='80%' border=0>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Song ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Artist</td>
        <td>Genre</td>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td>Lyrics</td>
        <td>Updated by</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $counter == 1;
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
    do {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['songid']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['title']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['artist']."</td>";    
        echo "<td>".$res['genre']."</td>";    
        echo "<td>".$res['language']."</td>";    
        echo "<td>".$res['lyrics']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$res['update']."</td>";             
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[songid]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[songid]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";        
    } while($res)
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: leave it like you had it to begin with: the `while` on the top of the loop

Comment: `while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { /* your table */ }`

Comment: You dont read the next result from your resultset inside the loop. So of course it goes on for ever. _Unfortunately we have all done it,_

Comment: $res never changes. If res is ever valid -> boom, infinite loop.

Comment: Seeing that your question has been answered, a little tip. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_* functions as these have been deprecated in 5.5 and removed in 7.0

Comment: what are you even trying to do with the loop ? Why are you using a comparing for no reason ? `$counter == 1;` DO....WHILE(condition) will keep looping until `condition` is false. It looks like $res is never false here

Comment: Two things wrong with this.  First, you're not fetching the next result in your loop so it will render the current result forever.  second, do... while assumes that there is always going to be at least one result.  What happens if the query succeeds but doesn't return any results because there are 0 matches?  Use while... do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$res = mysql_fetch_array($result);` at the end of the loop. Currently, the `while` statements checks if $res is (still) truthy, but it never changes, so it will always evaluate to TRUE (and so, the loop will always continue to run).

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to write the same thing as Daan Meijer. `res` never changes and so its always `true` for the while-statement.  I just want to add that `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` works a littlebit faster than `mysql_fetch_array($result)`. So if you have a big database,  `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` is the better choice.

Comment: Well, when it comes to code style and implementation choices, I might have one or two other tips for OP ;)